# How to store audio file in sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, asihttprequest

I am developing an iPhone application for an audio player. I want to give some options to the user so they can listen to the song/music by streaming or they can download the audio file and store in sqlite database. I know how to stream the audio files in the app programmatically. But I don’t know how to store the downloaded audio file in sqlite database using BLOB. Additionally, after storing the audio file in the sqlite DB I need to fetch the audio file and play the song. How do I fetch the audio file from sqlite DB?

This is my code for downloading the audio file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fileurl.com/example.mp3"];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dataPath]]; 

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Why do you want to store it in a database?  Storing large amounts of binary data in a relational database is not a good idea; what is generally done is storing the data in a normal file and just store it's name in the database.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your response. please give me proper guidance. i am entirely new to iOS development..

Comment: It's got nothing do to with iOS; I would have the same comment regardless of platform/language/etc.

Comment: Hi Satya, I thought to raise an awareness into your project. There are various types of copyrights associated with audios. Some allow streaming only, and do not allow the digital data to be stored on your device. I believe you have already addressed this matter.

Comment: Why don't you do homework before requesting the whole bunch of code for saving data as blob?  The I'm a beginner excuse is not a ticket for a free lunch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend to store binary files in database as blobs.
it will make you a problem with growing database file size in future. You will have to implement smart vacuum operation which is very slow on large data amounts.
My strong opinion: the files must be stored in file system. Store your file in application Documents folder and store a kind of link to them in database.

Comment: @heximal Thanks for your guidance. but i got confuse how to store file in application Documents folder will you provide any sample code..

Comment: @heximal i can't understand how to store audio file in sqlite DB and how to fetch audio file from sqlite DB will you give me example or sample code. i will try to understand.. Thanks in advance

Comment: in the answer below Chirag D jinjuwadiya i demostrated how to store files to documents folder. do you have already any code in your project that deals with sqlite?

Comment: @heximal till now i did not write any sqlite related code.. so give me any sample code how to store audio file in sqlite DB and how to fetch audio file from sqlite DB. so i can easily understand.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can download file and write audio file using NSDocumentDirectory in app. Documents folder like

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"audio.mp3"]];
[{your audio file in NSData} writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

now store only "audio.mp3" in database

when you retrieve data from database that give you name like

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:{database store name}]];
```

note **if you store full path that not working because Documents foldar path change whenever you run app.**

Comment: Thanks for your response. now how to fetch the audio file from sqlite DB

Comment: Why would you store the files in the documents folder?

Comment: you can`t store file in database.  write that  file in document Dic. and just get write path and store that path in database.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but that doesn't mean you have to store the files in the Documents folder, which is visible in iTunes etc under certain circumstances.  There are other folders to use instead...

Comment: I can be wrong, but Documents folder contents may be hidden for iTunes by setting UIFileSharingEnabled plist parameter to NO. anyway, trojanfoe is right, it's better to use some different folder (e.g. Library) if you don't want everybody to see your apps internals.

Comment: No it will not be Visible in iTunes